# setImeOptions in EditTextPreference

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, edittextpreference, imeoptions

I have a Settingsactivity (big backwards compability needed), where I add items from xml, and some programmatically.

So far it worked fine, but now I faced a problem again.
In xml I was able to set "setImeOptions" for EditTextPreference, but programatically, I can't. Android Studio tells me, there is no such method, when I try.

I hope someone can help me.

kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer:
Hope it can help some devs.

In my case, I had a general Preference, which I instanced according to other options, so I had like:

`Preference myPref = new EditTextPreference();`

How I got the IME options to work:

`EditTextPreference myEdTePref = (EditTextPreference) myPref;
 myEdTePref.getEditText().setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);`